# How to change custom entry point in a dockerfile to apply migrations to sqlserver before run the ASP.NET Core Web application?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, sql-server-linux

It is a VSTudio 2017 ASP.NET Core Web application project with SQL Server 2017 for Linux using Docker-compose. The dockerfile is:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY CoreWebApp/CoreWebApp.csproj CoreWebApp/
RUN dotnet restore CoreWebApp/CoreWebApp.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/CoreWebApp
RUN dotnet build CoreWebApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish CoreWebApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreWebApp.dll"]
```

and the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sql.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Sql_Admin1
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5434:1433"
    container_name: sqlserverlnx-2017

  corewebapp:
    image: corewebapp:dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CoreWebApp/Dockerfile
    container_name: corewebapp
    depends_on:
      - sql.data
```

I want to apply migrations to the database before the application starts. Based on the setp 4 of this guide at [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/) I replaced the ENTRYPOINT line of my Dockerfile by this:

```
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreWebApp.dll"]
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh 
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

And created an entrypoint.sh file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -e 
run_cmd="dotnet CoreWebApp.dll" 

until dotnet ef database update; do 
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up" 
sleep 1 
done 

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command" 
exec $run_cmd
```

But the migration does not apply. I can see the build output that the entrypoing.sh is executed with no errors as in the following log tail:

```
##... previous log steps removed for simplicity
2>**Step 18/18 : CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh**
2> ---> Running in 2dbecae7cd43
2>Removing intermediate container 2dbecae7cd43
2> ---> 878096c73494
2>Successfully built 878096c73494
2>Successfully tagged corewebapp:dev
2>docker-compose  -f "G:\Dockerizing ASPNet Core\CoreWebApp\docker-compose.yml" -f "G:\Dockerizing ASPNet Core\CoreWebApp\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "G:\Dockerizing ASPNet Core\CoreWebApp\obj\Docker\docker-compose.vs.release.g.yml" -p dockercompose7669752967822022310 --no-ansi up -d --no-build
2>sqlserverlnx-2017 is up-to-date
2>Recreating corewebapp ...
2>Recreating corewebapp ... done
```

[Edit:]
I entered to the container by PowerShell console and found some problems: 
1. The code page of entrypoint.sh was not Unix style. Fixed.
2. The resulting image does not include dotnet SDK then it fails at:

```
until dotnet ef database update; do
```

with the following error:

*Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409*

I replaced the final image at the last stage in the Dockerfile to use *"build"* instead *"base"* like this:

```
FROM build AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
```

and definitely the dotnet sdk is included in the final image but it does not solve the problem. Running manually the migration now produces the following error: 
*"No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option"*

Comment: did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem as described (dotnet sdk 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

For `dockerfile` without `RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh`, I suggest you try like

```
WORKDIR /src/CoreWebApp
RUN dotnet build CoreWebApp.csproj -c Release -o /app
Run dotnet ef database update
```